# Calculate width dynamically (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, dynamic, width, conditional-statements

HTML:

```
<div class="parent">
    <div class="one"></div>
    <div class="two"></div>
    <div class="three"></div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
parentWidth = $(".parent").outerWidth(true);
oneWidth = $(".parent .one").outerWidth(true);
twoWidth = $(".parent .two").outerWidth(true);
$('.parent .three').width( parentWidth - oneWidth - twoWidth);
```

But the thing is, either DIV .one or .two may not exist some times, how do I modify the jQuery for it?

Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can check if an element exists by checking its length property:

```
parentWidth = $(".parent").outerWidth(true);
oneWidth = $(".parent .one").length ? $(".parent .one").outerWidth(true):0;
twoWidth = $(".parent .two").length ? $(".parent .two").outerWidth(true):0;
$('.parent .three').width( parentWidth - oneWidth - twoWidth);
```

Comment: -1 for non-systematic approach and for violation of the DRY principle.

Comment: Thanks for explaining your downvote, I agree it's not the most elegant solution.

Answer (score 4):

Why don't you just check whether the result of $ function is empty ? ;) That way you can easily find out whether the div exists and simply set the width to 0 in that case, e.g.

```
oneDiv = $(".parent .one");
oneWidth = oneDiv.length == 0 ? 0 : oneDiv.outerWidth(true);
```

Comment: `$(selector)` will never give you `null`. If there is no matching element you will simply get an empty list wrapper. You would need to check eg. `$('.parent .one').length`.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, I'll fix it. I am actually coming from the world of Prototype where the $ gives you null for non-existing element.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code:

```
var third = $('.parent .three');
var wantedWidth = third.parent().outerWidth(true);

third.siblings().each(function(){
    wantedWidth -= $(this).outerWidth(true);
});

third.width(wantedWidth);
```